# Extend proto Array

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-programming

I have a question with the prototypes.
I'm doing a project and I want to create a small library of functions for Array, I have 3 possibilities.

**Extend the Array prototype (But I understand that it is not recommended)**

```
Array.prototype.arrayMax = function () {
    return Math.max(...this)
}
```

**Create a subclass of Array.**

```
function MyArray(...args) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(args,MyArray.prototype)
    return args;
}
MyArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
MyArray.prototype.arrayMax = function () {
    return Math.max(...this)
}
```

**Create a file with the different functions where the Array passes through the parameter.**

```
const arrayMin = arr => Math.min(...arr);
```

If we take this option, I use JS O.O and my structure of directory is
[image: Structure of directory]

Where can add I this archive js.

**What would be the most correct option?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the third option (implementing functions) is the optimal one because adding functions to built-in prototypes is a bad idea: how do you solve ambiguities? What would happen if other library adds a function with the same name to `Array.prototype`?

The second option wouldn't have the ambiguity issue, but in #1 and #2 you lose the chance to use syntax to declare arrays (i.e. `[]`).

About where to place that code, it's subjective. I would put it in a folder called `common` or `shared`, or just at the root of your workspace.

Comment: @RamsésFernández Great! It's all about good practices :) You're welcome